# can i install ubuntu on my laptop (dell inspiron 14z-5423)

Tags: inspiron

I have tried to install ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop, which is a dell inspiron 14z ultrabook, model number 5423. While booting with a pen drive, I selected the "try ubuntu" option. I then created the necessary partitions using gparted. Then when I tried to install ubuntu the install manager couldn't find the partitions created by me nor any other partition which was actually present.

Comment: Could you post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` from a terminal on your live USB?

Answer (score 0):

In Windows exist one option to disable hardware acceleration in intel software, after that the instalation will recognize the partitions, you can do it just running windows, BIOS no!!!!